# Get the dynamic Table row (TR) html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a html table generated dynamically here is the structure

```
row 1 headings
row 2 headings 

all dynamic rows such as values with text boxes and select boxes 

last row with add button
last row with another button
```

Now in the above table how how do i get the last dynamic row html content so that when i click on a button  i can add a new row same as previous row . I tried many statements How do i get  the last dynamic row content in table that is before 2 buttons

```
tr= $("#Tbl tr:last").html(); //outputs row with add button only but looking for last dynamic row before the add button
```

Comment: We don't need to see your 'structure'; we need to see you HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `tbody` to hold dynamic rows, and a `tfoot` for bottom rows with button controls, then search within `tbody`for last row

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have this structure

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
       <tr>...</tr>
       <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>...</tr>
       ....
       <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr><button id="add">Add</button></tr>
    <tfoot>  
</table>
```

To add a copy of the last row to the table do something like this (untested)

```
$(function() {
   $("#add").click(function() {
       var $table = $("#mytable tbody"),
           lastRow = $table.find("tr:last-child");

       $table.append(lastRow.clone());
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want to change the non-dynamic rows from `tr` to `thead` and `tfoot`, so when you get the last `tr` you can get the one you want

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/FuHuT/
Note that the last `tr` element is red

Answer (score 0):

With what you have, I think `.prev` is what you need. `:last` selector will give you the last row with the buttons and the `.prev` would give you the last row before the buttons.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/bF2JP/2/)

```
tr= $("#Tbl tr:last").prev().html();
```

Ideally, it is best to have your control buttons inside `tfoot` then in that case you can simply use `$("#Tbl tbody tr:last")` which will be the last dynamic row.

Comment: :It would give me "last row with add button" This was also tested

Comment: Did you try using .prev? Can you try the demo and let me know how it is different from your code. I think you should share your markup.